# PI integral anti-windup with dynamic saturation limit

Tags: control, pid-controller, automation

I have a controller to control the power output of a solar inverter and I'm not sure how to implement the integral anti-windup. The problem I'm facing is the actual output power is dependent on the solar irradiance and therefore the saturation limit is not a fixed value.

An example of wind-up occurring:
Solar Max Capacity: 100 kW
Solar available (due to low irradiance): 80 kW

The controller's setpoint is left at 100 kW. The inverter reaches 80 kW through the PI controller. Once it reaches 80 kW the error of 20 kW persists and winds up the integral term.

The challenge I have is how to calculate the saturation limit so I can freeze the integral term. Noting that the saturation limit is dynamic and will change dependent on the solar irradiance.

Comment: How do you implement anti-windup at the moment?

Comment: Umh, stop integrating when the system output is saturated? Some control somewhere will have a limit, right?

Comment: I suspect that things can be seen differently: is it a problem of choosing a limit for the integral component, or rather choose the right setpoint? As noted in the comment above, often PIDs "freeze" the integral accumulator when the output is saturated (at its max): not perfect, but still quite correct.